# Name 'flight_Num' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'

Tags: java, javadoc, checkstyle

I keep getting this error when I run checkstyle on my program:

```
    NonRefundable.java:20:28: Name 'flight_Num' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'.
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to correct this. Here are the comments for this particular error:

```
/** Comments.
  *
  * @param flight_Num the flight number.
  * @param trip_Data the information stored in the Itinerary object.
  * @param base_Fare the double representing the initial cost of the trip.
  * @param fare_AdjustmentFactor the number factored into the baseFare and 
            discountFactor used to calculate totalFare.
  * @param discount_Factor the number factored into baseFare and 
  *         fare_AdjustmentFactor to calculate totalFare.
  */
  NonRefundable(String flight_Num, Itinerary trip_Data, double base_Fare,
            double fare_AdjustmentFactor, double discount_Factor) {

     super(flight_Num, trip_Data, base_Fare, fare_AdjustmentFactor);
     this.discountFactor = discount_Factor;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Name 'flight_Num' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'

means that the _ character in flight_Num is not allowed.

Comment: If it's not allowed, then how would you rename this variable?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky How you renamed the constant with above error? Even I am also facing same error

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the checkstyle documentation, and I expect you will see this when you fix the first problem, but remove the underscore from the parameter names.

```
NonRefundable(String flightNum, Itinerary tripData, double baseFare,
        double fareAdjustmentFactor, double discountFactor)
```

http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_naming.html

You can look at various style guides and the parameter name tends to be camel-cased, as shown in this particular one.

http://www.cwu.edu/~gellenbe/javastyle/parameter.html

Answer (score 0):

[Since Checkstyle 3.0](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_naming.html#ParameterName)

If it is not possible to remove the underscore it is possible to suppress this with:

```
// SUPPRESS CHECKSTYLE ParameterName
NonRefundable(...)
```

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4023185/6413377)