# configure checkstyle to ignore an empty catch block

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

in my team we use checkstyle to improve our coding standards, but now we came across a rule which could be improved.

The Empty Block rule gives us a warning about an empty catch block (without java code and without comment), but with the standard configuration it generates also a warning if the block contains a comment.

e.g.

The two should not result a warning:

```
try {
    // some code
} catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
    // ignore
}

try {
    // some code
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    logger.debug("some debug");
}
```

This should result a warning:

```
try {
    // some code
} catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {

}
```

How can we improve checkstyle to give us only a warning, if no comment and no java code is in the catch block?

I looked for a solution, but I stackoverflow and google didn't have any.

Can someone help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023185/how-to-disable-a-particular-checkstyle-rule-for-a-particular-line-of-code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general question of how to tailor Checkstyle is ansered by this Question:

- [How to disable a particular checkstyle rule for a particular line of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023185/how-to-disable-a-particular-checkstyle-rule-for-a-particular-line-of-code)

The Checkstyle documentation for tailoring the checking of blocks is here:

- http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_blocks.html

And the specific style configuration you need is:

```
  <module name="EmptyBlock">
    <property name="option" value="text"/>
    <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_CATCH"/>
  </module>
```

Comment: While this was true when answered, it is now EmptyCatchBlock as mentioned below.

Answer (score 2):

That problem was addressed at https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/571 , new Check was created - EmptyCatchBlock  - http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_blocks.html#EmptyCatchBlock

In configuration EmptyBlock , please remove CATCH token, as validation will done by different Check now