# Suppressing Google Checkstyle warnings via checkstyle-suppressions.xml

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle

I'm using [`google_checks.xml`](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml) as a CheckStyle config in my Gradle project.

I need to be able to suppress the `MemberName` warning in one of my classes, and I can do so using `@SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:MemberName")` if and only if I add `SuppressWarningsHolder` and `SuppressWarningsFilter` to `google_checks.xml`
per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55828009/3846321).

The problem is that I update `google_checks.xml` regularly, and I don't want to remember to need to re-add these, so I'd like to handle these suppressions in a separate `checkstyle-suppressions.xml` file. This should be doable per this section of `google_checks.xml`:

```
  <module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property default="checkstyle-suppressions.xml" name="file"
      value="${org.checkstyle.google.suppressionfilter.config}"/>
    <property name="optional" value="true"/>
  </module>
```

However, I can't figure out how to get it to look for this file in my project's root directory instead of in the default `.gradle\daemon\6.5.1\checkstyle-suppressions.xml` path. How can I point it to another location?

If I set `value="${config_loc}/checkstyle-suppressions.xml"`, it does what I want, but we're back to the problem of me not wanting to have to modify `google_style.xml`.

It seems like I need to set the `org.checkstyle.google.suppressionfilter.config` system property somehow, but I'm not sure where to do this in my Gradle config files, or what exactly to set it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As its a system property, you can override it in the `build.gradle` as per below config, say you have `checkstyle-suppressions.xml` in the project root folder.

> NOTE: The config file is pointing to google_checks.xml from the checkstyle jar, and is not part of your project.

```
System.setProperty( "org.checkstyle.google.suppressionfilter.config", project.projectDir.toString()+"/checkstyle-suppressions.xml" )
checkstyle {
    toolVersion = checkStyleVersion
    configFile = file("/google_checks.xml")
    ignoreFailures = false
    showViolations = false
    maxWarnings = 0
}
```

Comment: I think the correct format for the SystemProperty is
`System.setProperty( "org.checkstyle.google.suppressionfilter.config", "$rootProject.projectDir/checkstyle-suppressions.xml")`

Comment: it work both ways, you can use string interpolation as well, as you suggested. The object project or rootProject should be used depending on its single or multi project build.

Comment: Thank you! Ended up using: `System.setProperty( "org.checkstyle.google.suppressionfilter.config", "$projectDir/config/checkstyle/checkstyle-suppressions.xml")`

Answer (score 3):

The [Gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/checkstyle_plugin.html) provides the [`Map<String, Object> configProperties`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.CheckstyleExtension.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.CheckstyleExtension:configProperties) option for this.

> The properties available for use in the configuration file. These are substituted into the configuration file.

So for suppressions.xml in the .checkstyle folder,

```
checkstyle {
    configProperties = [
        "org.checkstyle.google.suppressionfilter.config":
            "${projectDir}/.checkstyle/suppressions.xml",
    ]
}
```