# Use @SuppressWarnings with the sonar checkstyle plugin

Tags: sonarqube, checkstyle

I want to enable the usage of `@SuppressWarnings` in sonar like described in this answer: [How to disable a particular checkstyle rule for a particular line of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023185/how-to-disable-a-particular-checkstyle-rule-for-a-particular-line-of-code/22556386#22556386)

But the only part where I can configure checkstyle specific behaviour in sonar is under Project Configuration -> Settings -> Java -> Checkstyle

When I add this configuration to the Filters Textbox:

```
<module name="TreeWalker">
  <module name="SuppressWarningsHolder" />
</module>
<module name="SuppressWarningsFilter" />
```

Then it doesn't accept the `@SuppressWarnings`. Is there a way how to configure this in sonar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible for the moment: a ticket has been created to support it: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARCHKST-22

Comment: Ticket has been implemented in SonarQube Checkstyle plugin 2.3.

Answer (score 1):

For the rule `checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.naming.AbstractClassNameCheck` use:

```
@SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:abstractclassname")
```

See also [SONARCHKST-22 SupportSuppressWarningsFilter](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARCHKST-22) as mentioned in benzonico's answer. This was implemented in the SonarQube Checkstyle plugin version 2.3.