# What is the "CHECKSTYLE" comment we add to a Java class to suppress file length?

Tags: java, checkstyle

I have a java class with > 2000 lines, and I have Checkstyle configured to allow lines upto 2000. I want to override this Checkstyle property only for one file. 
How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023185/how-to-disable-a-particular-checkstyle-rule-for-a-particular-line-of-code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable a particular checkstyle rule for a particular line of code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023185/how-to-disable-a-particular-checkstyle-rule-for-a-particular-line-of-code)

Answer (score 2):

In Checkstyle code itself there is [`TokenTypes`](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/java/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/TokenTypes.java) class that is huge.

Solution that Checkstyle developers use currently is to suppress that file by specifying it in [`suppressions.xml`](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_filters.html#SuppressionFilter):

```
<suppressions>
    <suppress checks="FileLength"
              files="TokenTypes.java"
              lines="1"/>
```

This mechanism is called [SuppressionFilter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_filters.html#SuppressionFilter).

Comment: what does `lines="1"` do?

Comment: the `lines` is intended to target what line the error is appearing on. In this case, it isn't required. See https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/filters/SuppressionSingleFilter.html

Answer (score 0):

Just place this comment as the **very first line** of your class file:

```
// CSOFF: FileLength
```