# Suppressing Javadoc 21 DocLint warnings specifically for "no main description"

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin, doclint

I just upgraded my build from Java 17 to Java 21. In Maven I have Javadoc set to [DocLint](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/javadoc.html#doclint) everything using the [Maven Javadoc Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html) `-Xlint:all` compiler option.

As is typical with Java classes, I have a plethora of getters in the following form:

```java
  /** @return foo. */
  public Foo getFoo() {
    return foo;
  }
```

In Java 17 that produced Javadocs just fine. Now in Java 21 I get the following warning (oodles of them!) throughout my large codebase:

> `warning: no main description`

It seems Javadoc now wants me to do this:

```java
  /**
   * Returns foo.
   * @return foo.
   */
  public Foo getFoo() {
    return foo;
  }
```

I struggle to understand the utility of this new warning. I would like to suppress this warning project-wide in the configuration.

I believe I can disable the entire DocLint group by using `-Xdoclint all,-missing`, but this will suppress *all* warnings related to missing Javadocs. I definitely want to be warned if I leave off the Javadoc altogether for a getter!

**How can I suppress *only* the Javadoc DocLint warning related to a missing "main description" if the `@return` is nevertheless present?** Alternatively, if this is not possible, how best can I communicate to the Javadoc team that adding more and more inane warnings that cannot be suppressed individually will at some point cause even those users (such as I) who like to keep our API documentation super tidy to abandon the user of the linter altogether?

While I understand that someone people will just turn off the linter entirely, I'd rather be more specific.

See also my separate (related) question [Turn off Java 17 doclint missing comment warning only for enums in Maven Javadoc Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73693330).

Comment: I agree with the theme of this question, but I would doubt there is a flag for it - it feels like a very minor adjustment for which a flag might be harder to justify in maintenance terms. I'd be inclined to suggest posting this question in the bug tracker for the linter project.

Comment: Yeah, that was the second part of the question: "…  how best can I communicate to the Javadoc team …". Do you happen to know how the DocLint team communicates and what they use for the bug tracker? If no one knows I'll try to track that down (pun unintended) when I get a chance to circle back.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I didn't see that part of the question. I assumed DocLint is open source, but I don't use it, so could be mistaken. I did a quick search myself, and surprisingly could not find anything. I can't see anything on GitHub either.

Comment: Oh, just a thought - can this linter output in XML or something machine readable? At a push you could just filter that output for cases you don't like.

Comment: This is regarding the console output of `mvn clean package`, so whatever files are generated separately won't have an impact. (The thought of creating a Maven wrapper and parsing out these inane warnings from `stdout`/`stderr` and discarding them crossed my mind, but that would be one crazy kludge.)

Comment: I don't know Maven, but I assume you wouldn't need to interface with Maven _per se_ - just pipe the output through a filter command, in the style of `grep`. But I appreciate it might not be an elegant approach.

Comment: Where is your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing this problem? I quickly tried to reproduce this, creating a method with a comment like yours in a Maven project, then calling `mvn javadoc:javadoc` from the command line on JDK 21. No errors. So please, show a POM.

Comment: @kriegaex I think part of the confusion comes because I indicated the Maven Compiler Plugin, but linked to the Maven Javadoc Plugin. You attempted to correct the typo by changing the link text to indicate the _Javadoc_ plugin, but I'm using the `-Xlint:all` flag with the _compiler_ plugin. However it does look like the warning is coming from the _Javadoc_ plugin, so I think I was getting confused myself. Try reproducing this using the [GlobalMentor Root POM](https://github.com/globalmentor/globalmentor-root).

Comment: (1) Then, why do you not edit the question to use the correct text for the correct link instead of commenting on my edit only? (2) Making a Maven project use this parent POM and adding a method according to your description generates Javadoc on JDK 21 just fine. Your description does **not** replace an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (3) The bounty has expired. Next time, provide a minimal, complete reproducer on time.

Comment: In my opinion it's useless to have javadoc for getter that does nothing else just gets a property. It would be OK if the getter was modifying data somehow. What I would like to know (and its similar to the question), how to prevent the same warning when I put javadoc to a record type, where I have only /** @param someParam someDesription */

Answer (score 1):

Seems unlikely to have such granularity.

As you perfectly stated the message and check was included in 21
https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-21%2B35/src/jdk.javadoc/share/classes/jdk/javadoc/internal/doclint/resources/doclint.properties#L43

[image: no main description]

And having reviewed the change that implemented the new check there's no clue that such granularity for disabling the check can be achieved (needed to clone due to github being incapable of showing such a large diff).

```
@localhost:~/dev$ git clone git@github.com:openjdk/jdk.git
@localhost:~/dev/jdk$ git diff jdk-17+35 jdk-21+35 -- src/jdk.javadoc/share/classes/jdk/javadoc/internal/doclint/Checker.java > ~/jdk.diff
```

[image: diff]

You'd probably be able to contact the team and/or submit your proposal/PR or feedback on this kind of changes, there's a community list *discuss@openjdk.org* as described in https://mail.openjdk.org/mailman/listinfo/discuss but it's highly unlikely you see a change on this regard anytime soon.