# How do I alter checkstyle configuration file when using sonar?

Tags: checkstyle, sonarqube

I'm trying to suppress specific checkstyle warnings in my code.  The default way seems to be to wrap code in comments eg: // CHECKSTYLE:OFF ... // CHECKSTYLE:ON.  At the very least I'd like to give a reason for which I found the follow post.  I don't know where the configuration file would be when using sonar, can anyone help?

[How can you suppress checkstyle checks within a block of code only for specific rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640110/how-can-you-suppress-checkstyle-checks-within-a-block-of-code-only-for-specific)

Recommend reading the documentation on SuppressionCommentFilter (it is buried at bit) for lots of examples.

An example of how to do configure the filter is:

```
<module name="SuppressionCommentFilter">
 <property name="offCommentFormat" value="CSOFF: ([w|]+)"/>
 <property name="onCommentFormat" value="CSON: ([w|]+)"/>
 <property name="checkFormat" value="$1"/>
</module>
```

You can then use the following to turn off the RequireThis check for a block of code:

```
// CSOFF: RequireThis
... code
// CSON: RequireThis
```

Answer (score 0):

Login to Sonar as admin, then go to "Settings" (link at top-right, next to your username), select the "Java" category, then the "CheckStyle" tab.

After that, enter the <module> section from your post above into the "Filters" textarea.